# YouCompleteMe not working after default install

Tags: vim, gvim

I was trying to install `YouCompleteMe` with `Vundle` and it installed fine (it downloaded the `git` repository I pointed it to). I went into the folder and ran install.sh with the clang semantics and everything seems to work fine except for that I get this error every time I start `Vim` and it attempts to start the `YCM` plugin:

> Error detected while processing VimEnter Auto commands for "*": E117: Unknown function: youcompleteme#Enable

In addition to this (if it's helpful) the Helptags section in `PluginInstall` has always thrown an error but it's never affected the execution of the plugins before.

The result of `run_tests.sh`:

```
/tmp/ycm_build.tYz9by ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Your C++ compiler supports C++11, compiling in that mode.
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (found suitable version "2.7.6", minimum required is "2.6") 
NOT using libclang, no semantic completion for C/C++/ObjC will be available
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.6") 
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/ycm_build.tYz9by
Scanning dependencies of target BoostParts
[  0%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/date_time/src/posix_time/posix_time_types.cpp.o
[  1%] [  1%] [  2%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/date_time/src/gregorian/gregorian_types.cpp.o
Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/date_time/src/gregorian/date_generators.cpp.o
Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/date_time/src/gregorian/greg_month.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/date_time/src/gregorian/greg_weekday.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/tuple.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/numeric.cpp.o
[  5%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/errors.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/dict.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/str.cpp.o
[  7%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/object_protocol.cpp.o
[  9%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/long.cpp.o
[  9%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/object_operators.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/slice.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/list.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/exec.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/import.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/converter/type_id.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/converter/registry.cpp.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/converter/from_python.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/converter/arg_to_python_base.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/converter/builtin_converters.cpp.o
[ 17%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/object/function_doc_signature.cpp.o
[ 18%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/object/stl_iterator.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/object/function.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/object/inheritance.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/object/class.cpp.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/object/pickle_support.cpp.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/object/enum.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/object/life_support.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/object/iterator.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/module.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/python/src/wrapper.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/smart_ptr/src/sp_collector.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/smart_ptr/src/sp_debug_hooks.cpp.o
[ 27%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/exception/src/clone_current_exception_non_intrusive.cpp.o
[ 28%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/basic_xml_archive.cpp.o
[ 28%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/basic_serializer_map.cpp.o
[ 29%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/utf8_codecvt_facet.cpp.o
[ 30%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/void_cast.cpp.o
[ 30%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/xml_grammar.cpp.o
[ 31%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/basic_pointer_oserializer.cpp.o
[ 32%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/extended_type_info.cpp.o
[ 32%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/binary_wiarchive.cpp.o
[ 34%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/basic_archive.cpp.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/basic_text_wiprimitive.cpp.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/text_iarchive.cpp.o
[ 36%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/text_oarchive.cpp.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/basic_pointer_iserializer.cpp.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/xml_iarchive.cpp.o
[ 38%] [ 39%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/basic_iarchive.cpp.o
Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/archive_exception.cpp.o
[ 40%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/basic_oserializer.cpp.o
[ 40%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/basic_text_iprimitive.cpp.o
[ 42%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/shared_ptr_helper.cpp.o
[ 43%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/extended_type_info_typeid.cpp.o
[ 43%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/codecvt_null.cpp.o
[ 44%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/basic_text_oprimitive.cpp.o
[ 45%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/basic_text_woprimitive.cpp.o
[ 45%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/polymorphic_iarchive.cpp.o
[ 46%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/stl_port.cpp.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/polymorphic_oarchive.cpp.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/xml_wiarchive.cpp.o
[ 48%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/extended_type_info_no_rtti.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/xml_woarchive.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/binary_iarchive.cpp.o
[ 51%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/text_wiarchive.cpp.o
[ 52%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/text_woarchive.cpp.o
[ 52%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/binary_oarchive.cpp.o
[ 53%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/xml_wgrammar.cpp.o
[ 54%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/basic_oarchive.cpp.o
[ 54%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/xml_archive_exception.cpp.o
[ 55%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/xml_oarchive.cpp.o
[ 56%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/binary_woarchive.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/serialization/src/basic_iserializer.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/atomic/src/lockpool.cpp.o
[ 59%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/system/src/error_code.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/filesystem/src/utf8_codecvt_facet.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/filesystem/src/path_traits.cpp.o
[ 61%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/filesystem/src/portability.cpp.o
[ 62%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/filesystem/src/operations.cpp.o
[ 62%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/filesystem/src/codecvt_error_category.cpp.o
[ 63%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/filesystem/src/unique_path.cpp.o
[ 64%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/filesystem/src/path.cpp.o
[ 64%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/filesystem/src/windows_file_codecvt.cpp.o
[ 65%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/regex.cpp.o
[ 67%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/wide_posix_api.cpp.o
[ 67%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/posix_api.cpp.o
[ 68%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/c_regex_traits.cpp.o
[ 69%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/w32_regex_traits.cpp.o
[ 69%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/instances.cpp.o
[ 70%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/regex_traits_defaults.cpp.o
[ 71%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/regex_raw_buffer.cpp.o
[ 71%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/icu.cpp.o
[ 72%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/cregex.cpp.o
[ 73%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/static_mutex.cpp.o
[ 73%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/usinstances.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/wc_regex_traits.cpp.o
[ 76%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/regex_debug.cpp.o
[ 77%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/cpp_regex_traits.cpp.o
[ 77%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/winstances.cpp.o
[ 78%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/regex/src/fileiter.cpp.o
[ 79%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/thread/src/future.cpp.o
[ 79%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/thread/src/pthread/once.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object BoostParts/CMakeFiles/BoostParts.dir/libs/thread/src/pthread/thread.cpp.o
Linking CXX static library libBoostParts.a
[ 80%] Built target BoostParts
Scanning dependencies of target ycm_client_support
Scanning dependencies of target ycm_core
[ 81%] [ 81%] [ 81%] [ 82%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/versioning.cpp.o
Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/Result.cpp.o
Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_client_support.dir/Result.cpp.o
Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_client_support.dir/versioning.cpp.o
[ 84%] [ 85%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierUtils.cpp.o
Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_client_support.dir/IdentifierUtils.cpp.o
[ 85%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/LetterNode.cpp.o
[ 85%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_client_support.dir/LetterNode.cpp.o
[ 86%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierDatabase.cpp.o
[ 87%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o
[ 87%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/CandidateRepository.cpp.o
[ 88%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_client_support.dir/IdentifierDatabase.cpp.o
[ 89%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/Utils.cpp.o
[ 90%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o
[ 90%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/LetterNodeListMap.cpp.o
[ 92%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_client_support.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o
[ 93%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/CustomAssert.cpp.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/Candidate.cpp.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_client_support.dir/CandidateRepository.cpp.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/PythonSupport.cpp.o
[ 95%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_client_support.dir/Utils.cpp.o
[ 96%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_client_support.dir/ycm_client_support.cpp.o
[ 96%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_client_support.dir/LetterNodeListMap.cpp.o
[ 97%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_client_support.dir/CustomAssert.cpp.o
[ 98%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_client_support.dir/Candidate.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_client_support.dir/PythonSupport.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library /home/josh/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycm_core.so
[100%] Built target ycm_core
Linking CXX shared library /home/josh/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycm_client_support.so
[100%] Built target ycm_client_support
Scanning dependencies of target ycm_support_libs
[100%] Built target ycm_support_libs
~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
./run_tests.sh: line 9: flake8: command not found
```

Comment: What result of `run_tests.sh`?

Comment: What is full error message?

Comment: That _is_ the full error message so far as I can tell.

Comment: Is `~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/youcompleteme.vim` (that's the file defining the `youcompleteme#Enable` function) part of the output of `:scriptnames` in vim?

Comment: It is part of that list yes.

Answer (score 1):

py module flake8 is needed

```
sudo pip install flake8
```